# CSS "~" Selector Not Working

Tags: html, css

I'm making a navigation drawer using pure CSS. Everything works, but the container won't budge when the hamburger is clicked. The hamburger itself does move. Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Home - BloNo Student Union</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href = "home.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li> 
        <li><a href = "campaigns.html">Campaigns</a></li> 
        <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
    <label for="nav-trigger"></label>
    <div class = "container">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.container {
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 5%;
float: left;
overflow: auto;
}
.nav-trigger {
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
    }

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .container {
    left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
    left: 215px;
}
```

Seems so straightforward, but it's not working. Once again, the label is moving, but .container is staying put. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: add `position` property for container its works.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the `position` property in `.container` class then how its works on `left`

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .container {
    left: 215px;
}
```

changed to

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .container {
        left: 215px;
        position: relative;
    }
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srsathish/pmp0wk0n/)